# C++ compiler warning - returning local variable

Tags: c++

I'm simply trying to overload a + operator and I'm getting this compiler warning

```
reference to local variable 'tmp' returned
```

Here is the code for the overload

```
const Int& Int::operator+(const Int& p) const
{
    Int tmp = value + p.value;
    return tmp;
}
```

Here is the class

```
class Int{
    int value;
public:
    Int() {}    // default constructor
    Int(int v) : value(v) {}
    Int& operator=(const Int&);
    const Int& operator+(const Int&) const;
};
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't return a reference to a local variable. Inside the `operator+()` function, you're creating a local variable called `tmp`. It will get destroyed as soon as the function exits. You can't return a reference to that variable, because it no longer exists when the calling function gets the return value.

Change your definition of the function to:

```
const Int operator+(const Int&) const;
```

It would build without warnings and work fine too.

Comment: Don't you think 'const' should be removed as well, to avoid extraneous copies ?

Answer (score 11):

What you try to do is to return a reference to a memory location that will be invalid the moment you return it.

The variable tmp will disappear when it goes out of scope (that is, when operator+ is finished).

Because your return type is Int&, not the value of tmp is returned at "return tmp" but a reference to tmp. This is not correct because tmp will not exist anymore after the method is finished!!

Solution: Do not return as reference, but as Int

Answer (score -2):

`tmp` has a storage class of `auto` and will disappear when we exit. The answer is to specify static.

```
static Int tmp = value + p.value;
```

The storage assigned to `tmp` will remain reserved for the duration of the program.

Comment: Be aware that a nasty side effect of this solution is that any subsequent call to operator+() will overwrite the previous value held by 'tmp'. This is by far the worst solution I can think of for this case.