# C++ arguments changing while running

Tags: c++, arguments, readfile

I've a very simple function that should read a txt file and return all lines by one vector of the type string. I've stepped trough it quite a few times with the debugger and the only thing i've noticed is that the value of "fileName" changes on the line of the ifstream declaration. What am i doing wrong?? Thx.

```
vector<string> readFile(char* fileName)
{
    vector<string> fileLines;
    fileLines.clear();
    string line;
    ifstream myfile (fileName);
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( myfile.good() )
        {
            getline (myfile,line);
            fileLines.push_back(line);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    return fileLines;
}
```

//////////////////////////////////

I have this function that should return the filenames of all txt files in the current directory.

```
   vector<char*> getFileList()
    {
        vector<char*> fileNames;
        fileNames.clear();
        WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
        HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        char currentPath[_MAX_PATH];
        getCurrentPath(currentPath);
        strncat(currentPath, "\\*", 3);
        if (hFind = FindFirstFile(currentPath, &FindFileData))
        {

            string fileExtension = getExt(FindFileData.cFileName);
            if (fileExtension == "txt" || fileExtension == "TXT")
            {
                fileNames.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
            }
            while(FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0)
            {
                string fileExtension = getExt(FindFileData.cFileName);
                if (fileExtension == "txt" || fileExtension == "TXT")
                    fileNames.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
            }
        }
        return fileNames;
    }
```

That's how the function is going to be called:

```
vector<char*> inputFileList = getFileList();
if (inputFileList.size() > 0)
{
    for (int a=0; a<inputFileList.size(); a++)
    {
        fileLines = readFile(inputFileList[a]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling with optimisations enabled?

Comment: your code is not sufficient.Better post your function call invoke code..

Comment: What do you mean with optimizations? I'm compiling with Mingw. Thx

Comment: it looks ok, how is the function called? specifically what is inside 'fileName' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bet would be that you get your filename from a function which returns a pointer to a local variable, e.g. something like this:

```
char * getFilename() {
 char Filename[100] = "/foo";
 return Filename;
}
```

The above isn't valid - `Filename` contents are on stack, and will be invalidated when `getFilename()` returns. `vector<string> fileLines;` will be located in the same memory, and therefore the data `fileName` points to will change when you step over the `vector` constructor.

EDIT: See e.g. [C++ compiler warning - returning local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303947/c-compiler-warning-returning-local-variable) for more information on this

Comment: I guess that's exactly my problem. But i don't know how i'm supposed to return it that it works for me...

Comment: @Tom: Use a `vector<string>` - not a `vector<char *>`. Then make `readFile` take a `const char *` and pass `inputFileList[a].c_str()` to it.