# Create string class without strings library

Tags: c++, string, cstring

I am trying to make my own string class without using the strings library ie. `#include <string>`

I am allowed to use c-style strings!

I have to make the `iString` ctor, copy ctor, dtor, and overload the operators >>, <<, +, *

My problem so far is that when I try to compile my work, I get this error for each of my `operator+` and `operator*` ... which is:

```
warning: reference to local variable s3 returned [enabled by default]
```

`s3` was just the `iString` object name.

here is what I have so far:

.h file

```
#ifndef __ISTRING_H__
#define __ISTRING_H__

struct iString{
  char * chars;
  unsigned int length;
  unsigned int capacity;
  iString();  // ctor
  iString(const char *); // copy ctor
  iString(const iString&); // copy ctor
  ~iString(); // dtor
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, const iString &s);
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const iString &s);
iString &operator+(const iString &s1, const iString &s2);
iString &operator+(const iString &s1, const char *c_str);
iString &operator*(const iString &s, const int k);
iString &operator*(const int k, const iString &s);


#endif
```

.cc file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "istring.h"
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

iString::iString(){  // this is my ctor
  chars = new char[1];
  length = 0;
  capacity = length + 1;
  chars[0] = '\0';
}

iString::iString(const char *word){ // this is my copy ctor from a c-string
  length = strlen(word);
  capacity = length + 1;
  chars = new char[capacity];
  strcpy(chars, word);
}

iString::iString(const iString &s){ // this is my copy ctor from an iString
  length = strlen(s.length);
  capacity = length + 1;
  chars = new char[capacity];
  strcpy(chars, s.chars);
}


iString::~iString() { //dtor
  delete [] this->chars;
}

istream &operator>>(istream &in, const iString &s){  // not done, don't worry

}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const iString &s){
  //out<<s.chars;
  return out<<s.chars;
}

iString &operator+(const iString &s1, const iString &s2){ 
  iString s3;

  char *new_str;// = new char[size];
  new_str = strcat(s1.chars, s2.chars);

  s3 = iString(new_str);
  return s3;
}

// tried a different approach 
iString &operator+(const iString &s1, const char *c_str){ 

  int size = s1.length + strlen(c_str) + 1;
  char *new_str = new char[size];

  strcpy(new_str, s1.chars);
  strcat(new_str, c_str); 

  iString s3(new_str);
  delete [] new_str;
  return s3;
}

iString &operator*(const iString &s, const int k){

  int size = (s.length * k) + 1;
  char *c_str = new char[size];
  for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
    strcat(c_str, s.chars);
  }

  iString t(c_str);
  delete[] c_str;
  return t;
}

iString &operator*(const int k, const iString &s){
  return s * k;
}
```

Comment: Since I've seen this misspelled a lot lately, including in your question: [bear vs bare with me](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/is-it-bear-or-bare-with-me)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ compiler warning - returning local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303947/c-compiler-warning-returning-local-variable)

Comment: Touché, @jogojapan. I just fixed the error anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't return a reference from `operator+( , )`

```
iString operator+(const iString &s1, const iString &s2){
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that s3 will have been destructed after the return, so when the caller finally gets the string, it will be a reference to a string that has already been destructed and is thus invalid.

I.E:  You're returning a reference to a string that is local to the function - it will NO LONGER EXIST when you reach the caller.

What you need is to return by value.  This way, the string will still be valid upon return.  With C++11 this is known to be efficient because of rvalue references AS LONG AS you provide move construction and assignment.  Also, in C++98 you can count on many compilers applying the return value optimization in many cases to make this efficient.

Comment: what I could have done was this as well:

iString &iString::&operator+(const iString &s1, const char *c_str)

Answer (score 0):

The warning indicates you are returning a reference to an object that is a local variable.  This is a problem because the local variables are destroyed when the function returns.

`std::string`'s `operator+` returns a new string object instead of a reference to a string object; you should probably do the same.  The alternatives would be to create a new object and return a pointer, or to modify one of the strings passed to the operator, neither of seem very good.